# Days lived calculator not producing accurate results always

Tags: c++, date, calculator

I have a small problem with this program. I am trying to create a c++ program that will calculate the number of days an individual has lived. it accepts three arguments called month, day and year. this is the whole logic behind the program:

1. first calculate for todays date and save into three variables called day, month and year and find the year difference
2. Suppose the year difference is 10, calculate the number of days in 9 years by multiplying by 365.
3. Supposing the input month is 5, calculate the number of days within 4 months by adding their corresponding number of days and add the resulting value to the total days.
4. calculate the number of leap years from the input year to the current year and add the value to the total days.
5. the final output is returned by the function but i get slight errors with some dates. the output is not always accurate. Any help will be appreciated.
   below is the whole code:

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <ctime>
   #include <cmath>
   #include <vector>
   using namespace std;

   bool IsLeap(int);
   int LeapCount(int);
   int current_year;
   int calculator(int month, int day, int year);

   int main()
   {
      cout << calculator(9,24,1994);
   }

   int calculator(int month, int day, int year)
   {
       int final_result;
       int day_difference;
       int total_days = 0;
       const int days_inayear = 365;
       vector <int> m_days = {31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};

       time_t theTime = time(NULL);
       struct tm *aTime = localtime(&theTime);

       int current_day = aTime->tm_mday;
       int current_month = aTime->tm_mon + 1;
       current_year = aTime->tm_year + 1900;

       if(year > current_year){
           return 0;
       }
       else if (year == current_year && month > current_month){
           return 0;
       }
       else if(year == current_year && month == current_month && day > current_day){
           return 0;
       }
       else if(year == current_year &&month == current_month && day <= current_day){
               return abs(current_day - day);
       }else
       {
           int year_difference = current_year - year;
           int day_difference = abs(current_day - day);
          for(int a = month+1; a < m_days.size(); a++){
               total_days+= m_days[a];
          }
       int leap_years = LeapCount(year);

        total_days+=(year_difference)*days_inayear;
       if(year_difference <= 1 && month < 2){
           leap_years -= 2;
       }

       final_result = total_days+leap_years+day_difference;
       if(IsLeap(year) && month > 2){
           final_result = final_result;
       }
       return final_result;
   }
   }
   bool IsLeap(int year)
   {
       if(year%4 == 0 && year%100!=0){
           return true;
       }
       else if(year%4==0 && year%100==0 && year%400==0){
           return true;
       }
       else{
           return false;
       }
   }
   int LeapCount(int year)
   {
      int difference = current_year - year;
      int count = 0;
      for(int x = 0; x<=difference; x++){
           if(IsLeap(year+x)){
               count++;
           }
      }
      return count;
   }
   ```

Comment: It would help to track down the problem if you provided a couple of cases where the results are correct and incorrect. If you are able to find a pattern of what are the cases where the calculator fails, it should be simple to figure out the part of the logic that is incorrect. Without looking at the code, are you tracking that you only need to add the leap days if that day is within the range? (it is not sufficient to know the year when it happened, but whether it is after the birth date and the current date

Answer (score 0):

Computing with dates isn't a particularly simple and straightforward task and it's easier to simply use verified algorithms rather than try to debug a broken one.

From Howard Hinnant's paper [*`chrono`-Compatible Low-Level Date Algorithms*](http://home.roadrunner.com/~hinnant/date_algorithms.html), here's an algorithm that computes the number of days since 1970-01-01:

```
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>

// Returns number of days since civil 1970-01-01.  Negative values indicate
//    days prior to 1970-01-01.
// Preconditions:  y-m-d represents a date in the civil (Gregorian) calendar
//                 m is in [1, 12]
//                 d is in [1, last_day_of_month(y, m)]
//                 y is "approximately" in
//                   [numeric_limits<Int>::min()/366, numeric_limits<Int>::max()/366]
//                 Exact range of validity is:
//                 [civil_from_days(numeric_limits<Int>::min()),
//                  civil_from_days(numeric_limits<Int>::max()-719468)]
template <class Int>
constexpr
Int
days_from_civil(Int y, unsigned m, unsigned d) noexcept
{
    static_assert(std::numeric_limits<unsigned>::digits >= 18,
             "This algorithm has not been ported to a 16 bit unsigned integer");
    static_assert(std::numeric_limits<Int>::digits >= 20,
             "This algorithm has not been ported to a 16 bit signed integer");
    y -= m <= 2;
    const Int era = (y >= 0 ? y : y-399) / 400;
    const unsigned yoe = static_cast<unsigned>(y - era * 400);      // [0, 399]
    const unsigned doy = (153*(m + (m > 2 ? -3 : 9)) + 2)/5 + d-1;  // [0, 365]
    const unsigned doe = yoe * 365 + yoe/4 - yoe/100 + doy;         // [0, 146096]
    return era * 146097 + static_cast<Int>(doe) - 719468;
}
```

*This implementation happens to use C++14 features, however converting it to C++11 or even C++98 shouldn't be difficult.*

This is a pretty clever algorithm. The details are explained in Howard's paper.

To calculate the number of days between two dates use this algorithm to compute the number of days from the epoch for two different dates, and then subtract those values to get a number of days between them

```
int main() {
    int serial_birth_date = days_from_civil(1994, 9, 24);
    int serial_current_date = days_from_civil(2013, 11, 24);
    std::cout << "Days lived: " << serial_current_date - serial_birth_date << '\n';
}
```

---

If you really want to debug your own algorithm you can use Howard's published algorithms as a baseline. Compare results of various components of your program with results computed using these algorithms to narrow problems down to individual components. Compare results for a large number of test cases and perhaps you'll see a pattern in the errors.